# Qt 5.8 и sqlite развертывание в windows

Tags: windows, qt, sqlite

Добрый день, пишу небольшой проект на Qt с использованием Sqlite. В линуксе, а также в windows с установленной средой разработки все работает без проблем. Проблемы начинаются, когда нужно запустить программу на компьютере без Qt.

Базу данных подключаю так:

```
databaseservice.h

class DatabaseService : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DatabaseService(QObject *parent = 0);

    ...

private:
    static QSqlDatabase db;

    ...
};


databaseservice.cpp

#include "databaseservice.h"

#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>

#include <QDebug>

QSqlDatabase DatabaseService::db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

DatabaseService::DatabaseService(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    db.setDatabaseName("1cprint.db");

    if(!db.open())  //true
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(0,
                          "Ошибка инициализации БД",
                          "База данных вернула ошибку - " + getLastError()); //Driver not loaded
        exit(1);
    }

    ...
}
```

При попытке открытия БД выдается ошибка Driver not loaded. Погуглив нашел, что проблема может быть в неподключении (или отсутствии) плагина *qsqlite.dll*. Пробовал класть его в подкаталог *./sqldrivers/*, как указано в документации, прямо в каталог с exe'шником, а также в *./plugins/sqldrivers/* - результата нет. Опытным путем (переименование файла *qsqlite.dll*) обнаружил: эта библиотечка подгружается из каталога среды установки (в моем случае D:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\plugins\sqldrivers), но не из каталога проекта.

Множество решений с *QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths, qApp->addLibraryPath*, найденных в интернете также пробовал, результата нет.

UPD: Все, разобрался. DatabaseService::db переделал из статического члена класса в обычный, все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался. DatabaseService::db переделал из статического члена класса в обычный, все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости, плагины Qt загружаются в момент конструирования класса QApplication, в случае использования статической переменной

```
QSqlDatabase DatabaseService::db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
```

Она создается при запуске программы, перед входом в функцию main, а соответственно до загрузки плагинов. Еще как вариант - пересобрать qt из исходников, указав

```
configure ...  -qt-sql-sqlite
```

Тогда поддержка sqlite сразу будет в QSql5.dll, без необходимости загрузки плагинов.